# Electric Field inorder for Fusion to occur

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion

If I want to do D-D -> He + n fusion in an electric field - what potential would I need?

So I know the coulomb barrier is at $U=k^2 \frac{e^2}{10^{-15}} = 1.44 MeV$

This is when the strong force takes over essentially.

Does this mean if I put a deuterium atom in a 1.44 MV electric field and let is accelerate into the other they will fuse? This seems very low?

What am I missing here? What field would I need?

Comment: $MV$ is a unit of potential.  An electric field would have units of potential per distance ($V/m$).  Your electron has to move all the way from one plate to another (assuming a $1.44MV$ voltage difference) to gain the $1.44MeV$ energy.  Is that possible?

Comment: Also your deuterium has inertia that are ~2*1800 times higher than those of an electron. When singly ionized this means your acceleration is $a = qE/m$ so 3600 times lower, your machine has therefore to be a 3600 m long to attain the same energy. Good luck.

Comment: Never mind length of what I would need. I am interested in the potential of the electric field I would need to create enough acceleration for this to happen.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape, the energy is dependent on the charge and the potential.  A proton would have a lower speed than an electron at the end, but the same energy.

Comment: @renegade: you're still in the real world and have to accelerate over a certain distance to perform work and thus store kinetic energy in your particle. BowlOfRed: True, I mixed that obviously up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is the difficulty of actually getting the nuclei that you are working with to actually hit each other.  Nuclei are tiny, so if you try to aim them at each other, you will probably miss.

[This page](http://physics.ucsd.edu/do-the-math/2012/01/nuclear-fusion/) suggests that at the energies in the core of the sun, only 1 in every $10^{26}$ collision events actually fuses.  Now this isn't pure D-D, and the energies are different from your example, but it does give a scale for the problem.

[This page](http://iec.neep.wisc.edu/operation.php) has at the bottom a graphic showing the cross section of reaction for common fusion products over a range of energies.  To make it work more than just occasionally, you need to have very high densities.  People do make tabletop fusors that generate small numbers of fusion events with high voltage.  It's just not useful for energy production.